# DocBook sources of "Starting with Lift"

Tags: scala, lift

By the looks of it, I wouldn't be surprised if ["Starting with Lift"](http://liftweb.net/docs/getting_started.html) has been created from DocBook. I looked in Lift's Git repositories, but I haven't been able to find the source DocBook documents. So, is it really based on DocBook? And if it is, is it available from some public repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't konw about Starting with Lift, but Exploring Lift is written in Lyx, which in my limited understanding is a font-end for TeX (or LaTeX).